# How to get Parse cloud code find result?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I run the hello job but the Select function return empty value.

I call the Select function by use `Parse.Cloud.define` and the result has value.

And the `Query.find` in hello job has value.

Please help me to figure it out.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("hello", function(request, status) {
var Query = new Parse.Query("yee");
Query.equalTo("PushTime", NowTime);
Query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var tp = results[i];
            alert("a");
            var mresult = Select(tp.get("ID"));
            alert("aa" + mresult);
            if (mresult != "error" || mresult != "undefined") {
                InstallationQuer = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
                InstallationQuer.equalTo("NO", tp.get("No"));

                Parse.Push.send({
                    where: InstallationQuer,
                    data: {
                        alert: mresult
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.error("error");
                status.error("error");
            }
        }
        console.log("success promise!!")
        status.success("success promise!!");
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.error("Promise Error: " + error.message);
        status.error("error");
    }
});
});

function Select(ID) {
var a = "";
var Query = new Parse.Query("Meeting");
alert(ID);
Query.equalTo("ID", ID);
Query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            a = results[i].get("Details");
        }
        return a;
    },
    error: function(error) {
        return "error";
    }
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `Select` function *synchronously*, therefore it returns before `Query.find` gets any chance to finish as it is an *asynchronous* function. Make your function return a `Promise` instead and wait for that promise to be fulfilled before processing the results further.